# jquery tree traversing help

Tags: jquery

> Update: I'll have to go back to the
>   drawing board on this one. Thanks for
>   all the feedback.

Hi All,

Given simple DOM:

```
<form id="form1">
...
</form>

<div>
   <div>
      <a href="#" id="export">Export</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Starting with id=export, is there a way to go up a variable amount of divs and then get the closest form id?

Thanks,
rodchar

Comment: How is your whole HTML structured? Could you e.g. just store the ID of the form in the `rel` attribute of the link? Upon a click on export you can just read this ID.

Comment: @Felix - the form id varies as well

Comment: What you say can be a very heavy operation if on a very crowded page, but if your page has a trackable structure you could build a custom function for it. So, if you can share more `HTML` it'd be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: You can try this, assuming the form has no parents:

```
alert($(this).parents(":last").prevAll("form:first")[0].id);
```

I think you will need to show more relevant document structure, as others have pointed out.

Comment: *Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector* . But `form` is not an ancestor of `a`.

Comment: It's not working for me since the top container div is a sibling of the form (I get undefined error)

Comment: Oops, I missed that. I assumed the anchor was inside the form, my eyes, they lied to me.

Comment: @all - I need to work on the structure a little bit more. Seems that I don't have valid html to begin  with. Sorry for any inconvenience. Thanks all for the feedback.

Comment: haha i was getting lost anyway :P `$("a#export").parents("*:has(form)").eq(0).find("div:has(a#export)").prev("form").attr("id")`